# Getting null for input type file field on jQuery .click()

Tags: java, jquery

I'm trying to upload a file using jQuery .click().I'm getting only file name when I do request.getParameter() in my controller. Further I cant read that file with only file name. 
But when I use action to my form I will get the object of the file. But I don't want to use action to my form.

My html is -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submitId').click(function(){
    var url=$("#urlId").val();
    var xsl=$("#xslId").val();
    alert(xsl);
    $.post('add.htm', {
        url:url,
        xsl:xsl
    },function(data){
        alert("done");
    });
});
});

<form:form commandName="domTool" enctype="multipart/form-data"
method="POST" >

        URL :
        <form:input  path="url"  id="urlId"/>

        Xsl File :
        <form:input type="file" id="xslId" path="file" />

        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitId"/>

</form:form>
```

And my java code is -

```
@RequestMapping("add")
public String add(@ModelAttribute("tool") DomTool domTool,HttpServletRequest   request,HttpServletResponse response) throws JDOMException, IOException{

    System.out.println("file---------- "+tool.getFile());
    System.out.println("Url---------- "+domTool.getUrl());
    return "success";
}
```

I'm getting value of url but I'm getting null for domTool.getUrl().

Please anyone help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload a file in this way (by passing its location). Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload) question for techniques that work.